# Get input element from Bootstrap typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I need to get the input element inside the "source" property:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
   source: function (query, process) {
      var element = $(this);
```

I'm expecting an "input" element, but I get:

```
[Dataset, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typeahead in Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 changed the way that "this" object was set.

I get access to input element in this way:

```
var element = $(this.$el[0].parentElement.parentElement).children("input").first();
```

Ugly...

Comment: What a hideous botch.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure if I fully understand your question :/

Instead of `var element = $(this);` use:

```
var element = $(this)[0];
```

Or better still:

```
var element = this;
```

**UPDATE**

> *source* – The backing data source for suggestions. Expected to be a
>   function with the signature (query, cb). It is expected that the
>   function will compute the suggestion set (i.e. an array of JavaScript
>   objects) for query and then invoke cb with said set. cb can be invoked
>   synchronously or asynchronously. A Bloodhound suggestion engine can be
>   used here, to learn how, see Bloodhound Integration. **Required**.

**References**

```
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#bloodhound-integration
```

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: I have already dig into these sites, but no luck. Maybe I'm forgetting something, because in another project using bootstrap 2.0 is working.